# Attempting to compare different tables and cut out rows based on comparison in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two different tables right now. These tables contain a series of information including one column being a specific date.

Example:

```
[Table 1]
Unique Identifier (Primary Key) / Date / Piece of Information
0001 / December 1, 2020 / Apples

[Table 2]
Unique Identifier (Primary Key) / Date / Piece of Information
0001 / December 5, 2020 / Oranges
```

I am trying to compare the two tables if the second table has a date that is AFTER the first table (for the same unique identifier), I would like to write this to a new table. There are a lot of rows in this table, and I need to keep going through the rows. However I can't seem to get this to work. This is what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def fluvoxamine_covid_hospital_progression(fluvoxamine_covids_that_were_also_in_hospital_at_any_time, fluvoxamine_for_hospitalization_analysis_only_outpatients_need_to_dbl_chk):
    df_fluvoxamine_covid_outpatients = pd.DataFrame(fluvoxamine_for_hospitalization_analysis_only_outpatients_need_to_dbl_chk)
    df_fluvoxamine_covid_outpatients.dropDuplicates(['visit_occurrence_id'])
    df_fluvoxamine_covid_outpatients.sort(desc('visit_start_date'))

    df_fluvoxamine_converted_hospital = pd.DataFrame(fluvoxamine_covids_that_were_also_in_hospital_at_any_time)
    df_fluvoxamine_converted_hospital.dropDuplicates(['visit_occurrence_id'])
    df_fluvoxamine_converted_hospital.sort(desc('visit_start_date'))

    i = 0

    if df_fluvoxamine_covid_outpatients.sort('visit_start_date') < df_fluvoxamine_converted_hospital.sort('visit_start_date'):
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: There's no need to sort on visit_start_date. Since you have a unique identifier, you will need to join the DataFrames on the unique identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to break it down into steps. I renamed your variables for readability.

```
# renamed variables
converted = fluvoxamine_covids_that_were_also_in_hospital_at_any_time
outpatients = fluvoxamine_for_hospitalization_analysis_only_outpatients_need_to_dbl_chk
```

For the first step, keep the first few lines of code as you wrote.

```
# Load and clean the data
covid_outpatients = pd.DataFrame(outpatients)
converted_hospital = pd.DataFrame(converted)
covid_outpatients.dropDuplicates(['visit_occurrence_id'])
converted_hospital.dropDuplicates(['visit_occurrence_id'])
```

Next, [join the data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) using the unique identifier column.

```
all_data = covid_outpatients.set_index('Unique Identifier (Primary Key)').join(converted_hospital.set_index('Unique Identifier (Primary Key)'), lsuffix='_outpatients', rsuffix='_converted')
```

Reset [the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with the unique identifier column.

```
all_data['Unique Identifier (Primary Key)'] = all_data.index
all_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Generate a mask based on the date comparison. A [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) is a series of boolean values with the same size/shape as the DataFrame. In this case, the mask is `True` if the `outpatients` date is less than the `converted` date, otherwise, the value in the series is `False`.

```
filtered_data = all_data[all_data['visit_start_date_outpatients'] < all_data['visit_start_date_converted']]
```

Note, if your data is not in a date format, it might need to be converted or cast for the mask to work properly.

Lastly, save the output as a comma-separated-value CSV file.

```
// Generate an output. For example, it's easy to save it as a CSV file.
filtered_data.to_csv('outpatient_dates_less_than_converted_dates.csv')
```

In addition to the official documentation for [pandas dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), the website https://towardsdatascience.com/ has many good tips. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I get a comment saying ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! Am I missing definining something properly?

Comment: Without seeing your data, I can only say that pandas is only able to load your initial data if it is in an acceptable format for pandas to read it into a data frame. That error message has been reported and answered many times, try googling for the specific error, i.e., copy/paste the error into Google.

Comment: Was it working before? If so, try modifying your function with the information from the answer provided. Good luck with it!